# raspberrypiとphpのPOST通信について

Tags: python, php, raspberry-pi, arduino

Arduinoで取得したデータをraspberrypiにシリアル通信で送り，
PC上でApacheでサーバーを立ち上げてraspberrypiからPC上にデータを送り，
最終的にcsvファイルで保存します．
2つのセンサのデータを保存するのですが，csvファイルの中身が

26.6

28.2

26.5

28.2

というようにデータ１，改行，データ2，改行，データ1，....
の順番で保存されます．
raspberrypiからのデータの送信は同時のつもりなんですけれどうまくいきません

raspberrypiコード(python)

```
import requests
import serial
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gpio_seri = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=10)
    gpio_seri2 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1',115200, timeout=10)
    while 1:
        gpio_seri.write('get')
        gpio_seri2.write('get')
        bio_data = gpio_seri.readline()
        bio_data2 = gpio_seri2.readline()
        print(bio_data)
        print(bio_data2)
        url = "http://10.0.221.101:8080/send.php"
        response = requests.post(url, data={'bio_csv':bio_data})
        response2 = requests.post(url, data={'bio2_csv':bio_data2}
```

phpコード

```
<?php
  $data1 = $_POST['bio_csv'];
  $data2 = $_POST['bio2_csv'];

  $datas=array(
    array($data1,$data2)
  );

  $filename = "data.csv";
  $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a');
  foreach($datas as $data){

    $line = implode(',' , $data);
    fwrite($fp, $line . "\n");
  }
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

原因が全く分かりません
Pythonやphpに詳しい方いらしゃったら教えて下さい

Answer (score 1):

２回`requests.post`で送信しているので、別々の行データになっている。
pythonは書いた事がないのですが、以下の様にPOSTデータを一度に送信すれば良いのでは。

```
response = requests.post(url, data={'bio_csv':bio_data,'bio2_csv':bio_data2})
```

Comment: 実行はできたんですけど結果が変わらないです...